# USB Device Removal in Windows 8

Tags: c#, winforms, usb, wndproc

I've got the following code the detect the arrival and removal of a Prolific Serial based USB Device.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        DBT changeType = (DBT)m.WParam;
        string portName;

        if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)// && changeType != DBT.OTHER)
        {
            switch (changeType)
            {
                case DBT.DEVICEREMOVAL:
                    portName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto((IntPtr)((long)m.LParam + 12));
                    // Device Removal
                    break;
                case DBT.DEVICEARRIVAL:
                    portName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto((IntPtr)((long)m.LParam + 12));
                    // Device Arrival
                    break;
            }
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    enum DBT
    {
        DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000,
        DEVICEREMOVAL = 0x8004,
        OTHER = 0x0007,
    }
```

My problem is that it seems as if the Removal event never gets sent in Windows 8? This code works for WinXp, Win2000, Vista & Win7, perfectly.

After monitoring the messages while plugging and removing the device, it seems as if Win8 never passes the correct removal message?

Here are the results under Win8:

Detection:

```
HWnd=1770298, LParam=0, WParam=7, Result=0, Msg=537
HWnd=1770298, LParam=98820448, WParam=32768, Result=0, Msg=537
HWnd=1770298, LParam=0, WParam=7, Result=0, Msg=537
```

Removal:

```
HWnd=1770298, LParam=0, WParam=7, Result=0, Msg=537
```

What I'm expecting:

Detection:

```
HWnd=590440, LParam=0, WParam=7, Result=0, Msg=537
HWnd=590440, LParam=1241588, WParam=32768, Result=0, Msg=537
HWnd=590440, LParam=0, WParam=7, Result=0, Msg=537
```

Removal:

```
HWnd=590440, LParam=0, WParam=7, Result=0, Msg=537
HWnd=590440, LParam=1241588, WParam=32772, Result=0, Msg=537
```

This last message never arrives in Win8??

Comment: Is ANY event triggered? - Put a BP in your WmdProc method to see if ANYTHING happens...

Comment: I've got the same problem. WM_DEVICECHANGE coming, but only with code DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED.
Googling this problem lead me to this post. My issue is detecting of USB serial device arrival and removal to safely open/close serial port and allocate/free resources. Some people told that replacement of PretranslateMessage to direct message map solves this problem in Vista/7, but I can't check it for my Qt 5.1 project as I use overriden "nativeEvent" method.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem simply by modifying my usb-serial driver.
Adding Upper Filter 'serenum.sys' over standard usbser.sys help with proper configuration, so the problem disappeared.

Some thing like this. Example from production code.

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=Ports
ClassGuid={4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Provider=%MFGNAME%
LayoutFile=layout.inf
CatalogFile=%MFGFILENAME%.cat
DriverVer=08/29/2013,5.1.2600.10


[Manufacturer]
%MFGNAME%=DeviceList, NTamd64

[SourceDisksNames]

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=12

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Windows 2000/XP/Vista-32bit Sections
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DriverInstall.nt]
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=DriverCopyFiles.nt
AddReg=DriverInstall.nt.AddReg

[DriverInstall.nt.HW] 
AddReg=DriverInstall.nt.HW.AddReg 

[DriverInstall.nt.HW.AddReg]
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,*ntkern
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,usbser.sys
HKR,,PortSubClass, 0x00010000, "01"
HKR,,"UpperFilters",0x00010000,"serenum" 

[DriverCopyFiles.nt]
usbser.sys,,,0x20
serenum.sys,,,0x20

[DriverInstall.nt.AddReg]
HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"MsPorts.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider"

[DriverInstall.nt.Services]
AddService=usbser,  0x00000002, DriverService.nt
AddService=serenum, 0x00000000, SerenumService.nt

[DriverService.nt]
DisplayName="Driver name"
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\%DRIVERFILENAME%.sys
LoadOrderGroup = Base

[SerenumService.nt]
DisplayName="Filter name"
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\serenum.sys
LoadOrderGroup = PNP Filter

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Vista-64bit Sections
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[DriverInstall.NTamd64]
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=DriverCopyFiles.NTamd64
AddReg=DriverInstall.NTamd64.AddReg

[DriverCopyFiles.NTamd64]
usbser.sys,,,0x20
serenum.sys,,,0x20

[DriverInstall.NTamd64.AddReg]
HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"MsPorts.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider"

[DriverInstall.NTamd64.Services]
AddService=usbser, 0x00000002, DriverService.NTamd64
AddService=serenum, 0x00000000, SerenumService.NTamd64

[DriverService.NTamd64]
DisplayName="Driver display name"
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\usbser.sys

[DriverInstall.NTamd64.HW] 
AddReg=DriverInstall.nt.HW.AddReg 

[DriverInstall.NTamd64.HW.AddReg]
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,*ntkern
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,usbser.sys
HKR,,PortSubClass, 0x00010000, "01"
HKR,,"UpperFilters",0x00010000,"serenum" 

[SerenumService.NTamd64]
DisplayName="Filter display name"
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\serenum.sys

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Vendor and Product ID Definitions
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; When developing your USB device, the VID and PID used in the PC side
; application program and the firmware on the microcontroller must match.
; Modify the below line to use your VID and PID. Use the format as shown below.
; Note: One INF file can be used for multiple devices with different VID and PIDs.
; For each supported device, append ",USB\VID_xxxx&PID_yyyy" to the end of the line.
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;[SourceDisksFiles]
;[SourceDisksNames]

[DeviceList]
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX

[DeviceList.NTamd64]
%DESCRIPTION%=DriverInstall, USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; String Definitions
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Modify these strings to customize your device
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Strings]
FullCompanyName="Your company name"
FullProductName="Your product name"
ShortProductName="Short name"
MFGFILENAME="FileName"
DRIVERFILENAME ="usbser"
MFGNAME="Manufacturer name"
INSTDISK="Installation disk"
DESCRIPTION="Description of the driver"
SERVICE="Name of the serenum service"
```

You could check Prolific driver to find such sections. As well i have found them and they use Upper Filter and Serenum, so device insertion detected successful. Also you could check newer driver from Prolific.

Comment: `serenum` causes a lot of other problems though, such as Windows automatically loading a mouse driver for non-mouse devices.  I have seen [other USB-serial drivers that provide an "Event on Surprise Removal" configuration setting](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?eventonsurpriseremoval.htm), so this surely is under your control in your own driver.

Comment: Thank you, Ben.
I'll write my own driver for future devices. Using USB CDC allows us to use device on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X without serious expenses. Linux and Mac OS detects our device as 'tty' and only Windows wants driver.

Comment: Based on "modifying my usb-serial driver" I thought you meant you wrote it.  Anyway, `serenum` is trouble.

Comment: Writing of our driver is a future plan for current project. So it was easiest way to provide CDC device support.
Everything works fine, and we don't meet any problem with missdetection and mouse driver loading. But i believe that code of serenum may have any mistakes.